# Do data controllers have fewer obligations to self-represented data subjects than to their solicitors or insurers?

Tags: england-and-wales, gdpr, data-protection, any-jurisdiction

Bob makes a data protection request to a data controller who tells him that they are unable to comply with it and that he should therefore have his solicitors or insurers contact them. Do these types of entities have special privileges when it comes to data protection laws?

Comment: Not under GDPR, no. But your scenario sounds like there might be non-GDPR issues at play, e.g. negotiating a settlement.

Answer (score 2):

## No

The only party with a right to do this is the "data subject". They can probably delegate that via a [POA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_attorney) as most other legal matters, but whoever gets designated as the agent has no more rights than the original data subject.

Their answer citing a solicitor or insurance strongly suggest there is missing context here and that data is probably part of some ongoing investigation or claims process. The missing context will be the explanation why the entity could not comply with the request.

Comment: Wouldn't the data controller be obliged to tell the data subject why they can't comply?  Why would they be able to deal with the data subject's lawyer or insurer but not directly with the data subject?

Comment: @phoog I assume that we are missing a *lot* of context here and the person is *already* in a legal battle via their insurer or lawyer and the entity does not want to complicate that or is not allowed to dodge or avoid that avenue for some reason. In some juristictions for example you can demand to only be contacted through your lawyer... so they may want to channel all communication through the lawyer to avoid to look like they circumvent that. Customer service agents might be advised to not to talk to that individual directly. Or any other reason really, we don't know.

Comment: No, the data controller are not aware of any lawyer nor insurers involved, and indeed Bob has never instructed either.

Comment: @Seekinganswers Can you explain what kind of institution this is? I have a hard time imagining any private company asking for solicitor *or insurance*. That does not make any sense. *Which* insurance? My dogs health insurance? Certainly not...

Comment: Well it is difficult as both this data controller and Bob are of course fully hypothetical entities, but I suppose the DC did not specify any further at all.

Comment: Let us suppose that it is a chain retail establishment responding to requests for CCTV footage that include both oneself and other individuals with the following statements: “if this is needed in relation to a crime or legal proceedings, please ask either the Police, your Solicitors or Insurers to contact us directly, and we will release the information to them. Please ask them to quote this reference number in their request.”

Comment: Seems fair. This is the context you left out and which helps makes sense of it: You aren't requesting information *on you* in that case, you are requesting information *on others*. That is **not** within your GDPR rights. It is up to the authorities, maybe lawyers and maybe insurances if they are involved. Who exactly can inquire about this is up to your juristiction, but it is not a GDPR request and they correctly denied it.